# Brand new large monitor; games run slow

Tags: windows-7, display, graphics-card, cpu

I recently bought the awesome [ASUS PB278Q](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16824236294) monitor and was happy with it until I launched Call of Duty Modern Warfare 3.

The game performed *awfully* on my Windows 7 machine (lags, freezes etc.), however I'm sure its performance was *way* better when I had my old 19" 1440x900px monitor. The settings remained the same.

My other specs:

- GPU: NVidia GTX 770 from ASUS,
- CPU: Intel Core 2 Duo,
- RAM: DDR2 4Gb,
- The motherboard is quite old - MSI MS-7345

These are not so cool but they meet the Recommended Requirements (for that game).

How to get that CoD game to work well with my new screen?

Comment: Are you playing it at the same resolution and settings?

Comment: That's your problem, at least. Try playing with the same resolution as the old monitor and check if performance is the same as it was with the old monitor.
Elaborating, you are quadrupling the graphical workload you now have because you have a resolution that is 4x greater that the one you had before.

Comment: If you want to play at your new native resolution you'll have to turn the graphics settings down.

Comment: @Ramhound When connecting a large external screen (like the OP's) to my laptop, the machine heats up so much that the CPU's thermal throttling kicks in and kills performance.

Comment: @DanielBeck He has a desktop, not a laptop.

Comment: @DanielBeck check the answer. More resolution implies more processing power, which in turn implies more power, which in turn produces heat.

Comment: @crystal Not only your GPU can't cope with the high res, but also your old CPU might bring the whole system down. Nvidia cards are not so much CPU dependent as AMD cards, but still most games are relying a lot on the CPU, not only on the GPU. Do you have any physics effects turned on? Try to switch them off, maybe you'll see an improvement. If not, the other things you can do were already said before: lower res, lower graphics settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to sum up what **Doktoro Reichard** explained in comments :

The performance of a 3D game depends on graphics settings, but the most important parameters is the resolution. The higher the resolution, the higher (O(n²)) the number of pixels to compute, and the higher the workload for your GPU.

Since you went from 1440*900 to 2560*1440, you almost tripled (284%) the number of pixels to compute, and thus, you mosty likely divided by three your FPS.

Your options are :

1. Buy a higher-end GPU (yours is pretty recent already)
2. Play with a lower resolution
3. Reduce the graphic settings.
4. Improve the other componenents (DDR3, latest generation CPU, SSD?)

I would personally go for a mix between 2 and 3. The fourth point is for me the lesst interesting, but can also be combined with the others. (please note that a new CPU/DDR will probably mean changing the motherboard too)

Comment: Want to add something about CPU bottlenecking, which may be a cause in itself. The OP said it was using a Core 2 Duo (incidentally the same I use), which is a pretty old processor. The graphics board needs to tell the CPU and vice versa on how everything in memory is organized and the CPU needs to constantly send information to the graphics board. If the CPU can't handle the amount of information being processed, no matter the power of the graphic board, the CPU will serve as the bottleneck.

Comment: True. And easily checked. Run the resource manager while playing a games. (e.g. run the game on the primary monitor, put the resource manager on the other monitor). Then check if the CPU spikes. For most games even an not-quite-so-modern core2 will do just fine.

Comment: An additional option could be to buy a second identical GPU to use in dual-card mode (hereby called "SLI" for nVidia cards)